# How do I properly inject loggers into the database layer of my code?

Tags: go

My main problem is how to inject loggers into the functions attached to the models?
So for example, if we have a User model

```
type User struct {
 id string `json:"id" bson:"id"`
 name string `json:"name" bson:"name"`
}
```

and then let's we have a function attached to it

```
func (user *User) Save() {
 ...
}
```

Now what I want to do with this is to create an struct that has logger and other information attached with it

```
type UserStruct struct {
 logger ...
 dbConn ...
 ...
}
```

Now my problem is that if I inject this into the controllers then they would have access to the objects that they don't need.
I can't find a nice way to isolate these from the controller and only inject the functions on the models into the controller.

Comment: Are you looking for `Dependency Injection` or `MVC pattern`, those are two different topics. Also i'm not sure to understand what you are trying to achieve. Can you clarify the question?

Comment: Looks like some kind of ActiveRecord. I have not yet seen anyone injecting this logic into a data object in Go.

Comment: @AnthonyRaymond I think that dependency injection would help me in the MVC pattern but I am unable to solve this problem because of being very new to Golang. So, if there's a better way than this I am open to it.

Comment: @bereal What would be a better way to solve this problem then?

Comment: @TauseefAhmad take a look at e.g. [Gorm](https://gorm.io/docs/). In general, I usually extract a persistent layer for all that logic, and pass things like `User` in and out like a value object.

Comment: @bereal I can't use Gorm because I am using MongoDB

Comment: @TauseefAhmad then extract a persistence layer that knows how to save and find all of those objects. Instead of `user.Save()`, write `db.Save(user)` or something like that.

Comment: @bereal I understand what you mean. The problem then is that we're using a file based logger, how would I inject that logger into the code of the persistent layer?

Comment: @TauseefAhmad this db layer will be a struct type with methods. Make all the dependencies fields of the struct and populate them when you create it.

Comment: Why does your database model care about logs?  What kinds of things are you trying to log?

Comment: Like for logging if the transactions have failed or other errors like that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than implementing an active record pattern in Go, I'd suggest using a persistence layer that receives all those data objects like `User`. For example:

```
type Persistence struct {
    logger logging.Logger
    conn   *mongo.Client
    // ...
}

func NewPersistence(...) (*Persistence, error) {
    // connect to mongo etc
    return &Persistence{...}, nil
}

func (p *Persistence) SaveUser(user *User) error {
    // ...
}

func (p *Persistence) FindUserByName(username string) (*User, error) {
    // ...
}
```